# What is the difference between running app and exporting unsigned app?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-build

What is the difference between running an app and exporting unsigned app (regarding the built `.apk`) file?

As my app fails to export with *Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1*, but when running it via *Run as Android App* it runs and installs on the device.

I searched all the questions and tried all the answers but nothing worked, I don't even know how to debug it, there are no errors, and no problems in the logs.

FYI, my app uses:

- ActionBarSherlock (by JakeWarton)
- ViewPagerIndicator (by JakeWarton)
- PullToRefresh
- GoogleAdMob
- GoogleAnalytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you're applying a private key to the app, it's just that in one of the cases, it's the [debug key](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) (which is generated automatically, at least in Eclipse environments) and in the other case it can be used to publish it, for instance, on Google Play.

(from the link):

> The important points to understand about signing Android applications
>   are:
>
> All applications must be signed. The system will not install an
>   application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed. To test
>   and debug your application, the build tools sign your application with
>   a special debug key that is created by the Android SDK build tools.

I actually have had your problem, but in my case I solved it by cleaning my App (and associated libraries) in Eclipse and repeating the Export procedure.

Comment: Can you publish an Unsigned App ?

Comment: Look at the link I posted. You can't publish an unsigned App. (it's in the quoted part from the link). And you can't use your Debug Key either.

Comment: I know that already (I have published more than 5 apps already), My main question is why would building Unsigned App fails While Running a Debugging App works?

Comment: Like I said, I've run into trouble like yours as well. Whenever I run into this scenario, I clean all associated Libraries (like ActionBarSherlock, which I'm using as well) and retry the process. Maybe you could close Eclipse, clean them manually and retry?

Comment: I tried to clean all and removed dependencies manually but still nothing worked

Comment: I suspect the issue is in the conflict between ABS and ViewPagerIndicator, This happened since Updating to the latest version of both.

Comment: I Deleted ABS and downloaded a fresh copy, Created new from existing source with different name and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you export it unsigned, no Android phone will be able to use the app, even if you set the setting to accept third party sources.  Try exporting a signed app, you'll have to create your own signature.

Comment: This isn't actually true. I've run apps I've generated on many phones, and I haven't even had to use the export facilities of Eclipse (or ant for that matter)

Comment: @Mike, No you're wrong, I'm not asking about Signed vs Unsigned, I'm talking about Debugging vs Unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

All android apps must be signed. Simply forget about 'export unsigned application'.
The difference you should know is about the ways you can export a signed application:

1. Running the app directly from eclipse - it is the same as 'export signed application' using default android SDK keystore localized in ~/.android/. **It is not possible to publish an app using this keystore**. Default keystore has the following configuration:

   - Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
   - Keystore password: "android"
   - Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
   - Key password: "android"
2. Exporting a signed application using your own keystore - in order to do this you need to generate your own keystore, set above parameters and use it when exporting you app. **Apps signed this way can be published**.

For more information about signing your app, visit [app signing page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).